# How to pass argument to java bash script?

Tags: java, bash

I have a simple bash script which runs my java program. Here is it:

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar target/my-jar-arch.jar
```

I want to pass arguments to this script, which must pass them to java program:

```
bash run.sh myArg -key 100
```

When I try to execute this line my app doesn't get any parameters. How can I fix it?

Comment: `java -jar target/my-jar-arch.jar "$@"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your invocation line to:

```
java -jar target/my-jar-arch.jar "$@"
```

Comment: Oh maybe you know how to make my script executable? If I run it `run myArg -p 100` I get `-bash: run: command not found`. Seams the problem is in my env.

Comment: It should be `./run.sh`. Unix systems won't automagically "append extensions" or whatever; in fact they don't have the notion of an extension at all.

Comment: The problem isn't in extension. It is in my .bash_profile I think.

Comment: is there any possibility to pass few bash variables in to the java -jar command?  Eg:- java -jar org.sample.jar $HOST $PORT  assume I already have HOST and PORT defined within my bash script.