# executing a jar file through a bash script

Tags: java, bash, shell

I want to execute a jar file using java -jar command from a bash script. At the same time I'm passing few parameters which I can access in my main method, using args[].

I'm able to do this without any issues if I try,

```
java -jar org.sample.jar localhost 8080
```

but I want to make these parameters configurable through few variables.

Eg:-

```
HOST=localhost
PORT=8080
```

When I try to use above variables like following, bash script fails silently.

```
java -jar org.sample.jar $HOST $PORT
```

I also tried using "$HOST" but without any luck. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

**I was using cygwin to execute/debug my bash script. Once I execute the same script using git bash it works.**

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap this in a bash scripts and using bash parameters.

Say you will have a script file sample.sh.

in sample.sh, it contains only one line, which is `java -jar org.sample.jar "$@"`

Then execute your jar file by `bash sample.sh -Host hostname -port 8080`

[Here is a post about how to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344194/how-to-pass-argument-to-java-bash-script)

**UPDATE**

To use variables in your bash script, your script will look like this:

```
Host="localhost"
Port=8080

java -jar org.sample.jar $Host $Port
```

I'm using Eclipse and I only wrote one class which has a main method and prints all the arguments. Then I used Eclipse to export a jar file and then used this solution and it worked.

Comment: Yes, but my requirement is to use variables which exist within my bash script. I don't want to execute my bash script passing arguments.

Comment: I don't see any difference, because you really don't need to use "" to define the host variable. As far as I know quotations required only if you have a white-space Eg:- local host

Comment: @udarakr Then check if your main method handles the parameters properly, since I've tested it and it had no problem.

Comment: I'm using maven-jar plugin, but that should not have any effect since I can execute my jar using "java -jar org.sample.jar localhost 8080"

Comment: If there is an issue within my java class it should fail for both cases.

Comment: @udarakr Okay, then I'm not sure what is happening. I used this way and never had any issue.

Comment: found the problem :) I was using cygwin on windows to execute/debug my bash script. Once I execute the same script using git bash it works.